# PHP Joomla Creating a right-aligned root menu item

Tags: php, joomla, menu

I have a menu written [here](http://aurorasvoice.org/) which contains root elements and secondary elements. I would like to add a root element, and unlike the other root elements, have this element aligned to the right. Can I do this using CSS, and if so, how do I apply a css style to the specific menu item element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. Every menuitem has a different class in this format: itemX , where X is the id of the menuitem.

You can set the width of you class="menutop" to 100% :

```
ul#horiznav.menutop, #horiz-menu ul.menutop {
   padding: 0 2px;
   margin: 0;
   position: relative;
   z-index:120;
   width:100%;
}
```

and set "float:right" to your specific menuitem, something like:

```
.menutop .itemX {float:right}
```

Replacing X for the id of your menuitem.